# Error handling with http.NewRequest in Go

Tags: http, go

I was using `http.NewRequest` to make a GET Request.

I deliberately tried to tamper the API url just to check if my err handling works.

But its not working as expected . In err  value is returned and I am unable to compare it.

```
    jsonData := map[string]string{"firstname": "Nic", "lastname": "Raboy"}
    jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(jsonData)    
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://httpbin.org/postsdf", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))


        request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        client := &http.Client{}
        response, err := client.Do(request)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("wrong")

        } else {
            data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            fmt.Println(string(data))
        }
```

The output is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

But I am expecting to print "Wrong".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The HTTP call succeeds (the call went through to the server, and response came back), that's why `err` is `nil`. It's just that the HTTP status code is not `http.StatusOK` (but by judging the response document, it's `http.StatusNotFound`).

You should check the HTTP status code like this:

```
response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("HTTP call failed:", err)
    return
}
// Don't forget, you're expected to close response body even if you don't want to read it.
defer response.Body.Close()

if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    fmt.Println("Non-OK HTTP status:", response.StatusCode)
    // You may read / inspect response body
    return
}

// All is OK, server reported success.
```

Also note that certain API endpoints might return other than `http.StatusOK` for success, such as `HTTP 201 - Created`, or `HTTP 202 - Accepted` etc. If you want to check all success status codes, you can do it like this:

```
// Success is indicated with 2xx status codes:
statusOK := response.StatusCode >= 200 && response.StatusCode < 300
if !statusOK {
    fmt.Println("Non-OK HTTP status:", response.StatusCode)
    // You may read / inspect response body
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should user the status code, you can also write a small handler for every http request that you create.

```
response, err := client.Do(request)
        switch response.StatusCode {
        case 200:
            fmt.Println("work!")
            break
        case 404:
            fmt.Println("not found!")
            break
        default:
            fmt.Println("http", response.Status)
        }
```

Comment: I get the following error with this solution: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference. When I ensure the request fails, the response object is not available??

Comment: If err is set and response is nil this will crash